# Error in printing BST traversal - Segmentation Faults

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I am coding to print out BST preorder and postorder traversals.

The class tree is defined like this

```
class BinSearchTree{
  char symbol;
  BinSearchTree  *lChild;
  BinSearchTree  *rChild;

 public:
 BinSearchTree(char letter) { symbol = letter;lChild = NULL; rChild = NULL;}
  BinSearchTree() { symbol = '0';}
  BinSearchTree* buildTree(BinSearchTree *tree, char letter);
  void printTreePreOrder (BinSearchTree *temp, std::ofstream &fp1);
  void printTreeInOrder (BinSearchTree *temp, std::ofstream &fp1);
};
```

I have used a simple recursion to create the BST

```
BinSearchTree* BinSearchTree::buildTree(BinSearchTree *tree, char letter){
  if (tree == NULL) {
    tree = new BinSearchTree (letter); 
    return tree;
  }
  else {
        if (letter<(tree->symbol))
        {
                tree->lChild = (BinSearchTree*) buildTree(tree->lChild, letter);
                return tree;
        }
        else{
                tree->rChild = (BinSearchTree*) buildTree(tree->rChild, letter);
                return tree;
        }
      }
    return tree;
}
```

But when I print out the traversal, I am getting segmentation faults. I use this piece of code for preorder and something similar for postorder

```
void BinSearchTree::printTreePreOrder (BinSearchTree *temp, std::ofstream &fp1) {
    if (temp == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        fp1 << symbol << " ";
        printTreePreOrder(lChild, fp1);
        printTreePreOrder(rChild, fp1);
    }
}
```

In my main code, I create my tree using

```
T = new BinSearchTree(str[0]);
    for(i=1; i<num; i++){
        fp >> str[i];
        T->buildTree(T,str[i]);
    }
```

and do traversal using

```
T->printTreePreOrder(T,fp1)
```

I have been trying to figure out the error since days and I think am committing a silly error. Any help is appreciated.

PS - Working on Ubuntu 14.04 and using G++ compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to decide where do you want the traversal algorithm to be, in the class or out of the class. Now the method is belong to the class but receive a parameter of the type of the class (this seem odd, and in this particular case are wrong).

`void BinSearchTree::printTreePreOrder (BinSearchTree *temp, std::ofstream &fp1);`

The correct signature should be:

`void BinSearchTree::printTreePreOrder(std::ofstream &fp1)` in this case you are iterating using the actual node as root the code would be something like:

```
void BinSearchTree::printTreePreOrder(std::ofstream &fp1) {
    fp1 << symbol << " ";
    if (lChild != NULL)
        printTreePreOrder(lChild, fp1);
    if (rChild != NULL)
        printTreePreOrder(rChild, fp1);
}
```

Or if the function is out of the class:

```
void printTreePreOrder(BinSearchTree *temp, std::ofstream &fp1) {
    if (temp == NULL)
        return ;
    else {
        fp1 << temp->symbol << " ";
        if (temp->lChild != NULL)
            printTreePreOrder(temp->lChild, fp1);
        if (temp->rChild != NULL)
            printTreePreOrder(temp->rChild, fp1);
    }
}
```

In this case you would need access to the members `symbol`, `lChild` and `rChild` in the actual implementation are private (or declare the method as friend).

Your problem is you are miss matching parameters and member variables, eg:

In your call to the `printTreePreOrder` method: `T->printTreePreOrder(T,fp1)` in this case `temp` would be `T`, `lChild` and `rChild` would be the child's of `T`, there is no problem here, let suppose that the two child exist, you print `symbol` of `T` and call `printTreePreOrder(lChild, fp1);` in this call `temp` is equal to `lChild`, but `lChild` and `rChild` are already refering to the member variables of `T`, and this is the problem.

In your case is probably better to be `in class` for not declaring the `members variables public` or `friend`.

It seem odd and wrong the return of the method `buildTree` (it have the same problem as `printThreePreOrder`. You don't have to need returning anything, the new data is inserted in the actual node or forwarded to one of the child, not need to return anything:

Code would be something like (in class version):

```
void BinSearchTree::buildTree(char letter){
    if (letter < tree->symbol) {
        if (lChild == NULL)
            lChild = new BinSearchTree(letter);
        else
            lChild->buildTree(letter);
    } else {
        if (rChild == NULL)
            rChild = new BinSearchTree(letter);
        else
            rChild->buildTree(letter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem of the segmentation fault which I was getting. But the output is still wrong, is there an error in the way I create the tree? I used the second approach that you suggested in which the function is out of the class.

Comment: Updated answer, see new recommendations.